# How to add time at which commands were executed to terminal on Mac? (change format)

Tags: macos, bash

The default format for my terminal line looks like this:

```
David-Mac-mini:~ david$
```

I'd love if there was a way for it to show by default as:

```
David-Mac-mini:~ david$ [Hh:Mm:Ss]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have edit or create your .bashrc or .bash_profile profile file.
Add the command `export PS1="\t"`

You can add the following lines to customize your Terminal prompt:

```
\d – Current date
\t – Current time
\h – Host name
\# – Command number
\u – User name
\W – Current working directory (ie: Desktop/)
\w – Current working directory with full path (ie: /Users/Admin/Desktop/)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this format: `export PS1="[\t] \h:\W \u$ "`

Comment: You don't need to export `PS1`; it's only used by `bash` itself, not any program `bash` might start.